# Generic, role based emails (e.g. root@ admin@, etc). Determining?

Tags: algorithm, email

I want to filter out generic, marketing based emails ("role based emails", e.g. orders@example.com, newsletter@example.com).

The Rapportive Chrome extension seems to label role based emails pretty accurately.  Not only does it get the ultra generic emails, but it classifies correctly non-common role based emails like slashdot@slashdot.org, nytdirect@nytimes.com, etc.

I'm looking for either A) a comprehensive list of role based email addresses or 2) an algorithm to determine whether an email is a  role based email (is there a header I should be looking at?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer:  most reputable mail list servers are including the List-Unsubscribe header in the email message.